# Angular2 @Input undefined when trying to bind to a string constant

Tags: angular

Maybe this is normal behavior, making a test, `this.myColor` It is undefined, but why? That mistake wrong in my code:

```
<h1 myDR [myColor]="red" > Test </h1>
```

---

```
import {Component, Directive, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDR]',
    host:{
        '(mouseenter)' : ' mouseEnter()'
    }
})

export class MyDi {
    
    @Input () myColor: string;
    
    constructor(private el:ElementRef) {
        
    }
    
    mouseEnter(){
      
        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.myColor;
    
        console.log(this.myColor);
     }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello World Angular2</h1> 
 
              <h1 myDR [myColor]="red" > Test </h1>
              `,
    directives: [MyDi]
})

export class App {
    constructor(){
        
    }
}
```

You can move the mouse over "Test" and look in the Console

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tBRrMuRI5LXOABvm6oG1?p=preview)</kbd>

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have to enclose your input binding in simple quotes, like this

```
[myColor]="'red'"
```

This will bind the `red` string to `myColor`. If you remove the simple quotes it will look for a class property named `red` which doesn't exist therefore it returns `undefined`

You can do it as I mentioned above, or you can create a class property named `red`. In this case it will bind to the class property.

```
@Component({
    template: `<h1 myDR [myColor]="red" > Test </h1>`
})

export class App {
    red: string = 'red';
}
```

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that accessing the DOM through `nativeElement` is discouraged. You should use [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html), [@HostBinding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/HostBinding-var.html) or the `host` property in `@Component` (the last two are equivalent). So you have three more options

- Using `host` property

```js
@Directive({
    host:{
        '(mouseenter)' : ' mouseEnter()',
        '[style.background-color]' : 'myColor'
    }
})

mouseEnter(){
    this.myColor = 'blue';
}
```

- Using `@HostBinding` (this case will set the color immediatly)

```js
@HostBinding('style.background-color') get color {
    return this.myColor;
}

mouseEnter(){
    this.myColor = 'blue';
}
```

- Using `Renderer` (use this instead of `nativeElement.style = 'value'`)

```js
constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public element: ElementRef) {}

mouseEnter(){
  this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.myColor);
}
```

Comment: Ohh, it's true, I feel stupid now.  thanks for your time.

Comment: @AngelAngel you're welcome. I updated my answer with something it may interest you.

Comment: its update is really useful, it is possible to adapt the title of my question to make it easier to access your answer with the information of the update, I think I could help others learn these ways

Comment: something like: @Input undefined Angular 2 using native Element, for example?

Comment: @AngelAngel I think it's fine like it is, I wouldn't worry about it. But it's your call, it's your question :P

Comment: Eric and @AngelAngel, Eric's update would be good to put into another question, "What are some good alternatives to accessing the DOM using nativeElement?"

Comment: Eric I just created a question that says @MarkRajcok http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108995/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-accessing-the-dom-using-nativeelement-in-angu

Comment: Can I ask where this comes from: "accessing the DOM through nativeElement is discouraged"?  angular.io is using nativeElement in their attribute directives example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler way for binding static text is

```ts
<h1 myDR myColor="red" > Test </h1>
```

See [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) under "One-time string initialization".

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EVJSSt?p=preview)

Comment: it is true, I had not thought, in that alternative thanks for your reply is good to keep in mind

Comment: Günter, this comment is for other readers (since we've had a good discussion about this in other comments):  I don't really like this shorthand notation because it looks like just an HTML attribute.  We have to examine the component definition to determine if `myColor` is an input property.  If it is, then this syntax also populates the input property with the value `red`. If it isn't, then it is just an HTML attribute. I find that ambiguous.  I much prefer to see the `[]`s whenever we want to affect a directive or a component property.  They immediately tell us that we're property binding.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Thanks for that explanation, I didn't understand the difference of using with [] and without [], and your explanation cleared it up. It is better to use with [] and set the value with a single quote inside a double quote string like `[prop]=" 'literalValue' "` because it is obvious that we are property binding, not just setting an HTML attribute. Also, this way it doesn't set that `prop` as an HTML attribute but rather it only creates a ng-reflect attribute.