# What are some good alternatives to accessing the DOM using nativeElement in Angular2?

Tags: angular

Taking as an example the following code, which are good alternatives to accessing the DOM using nativeElement

```js
import {Component, Directive, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myDR]',
    host:{
        '(mouseenter)' : ' mouseEnter()'
    }
})

export class MyDi {

    @Input () myColor: string;

    constructor(private el:ElementRef) {

    }

    mouseEnter(){

        this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.myColor;

        console.log(this.myColor);
     }
}
```

This is a <kbd>[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vd418yfGj9auqBKeL5Cs?p=preview)</kbd> for you test more easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since accessing directly to DOM through `nativeElement` is discouraged you have three options

- Using `host` property (this will set the color immediatly)

```js
@Directive({
    host:{
        '(mouseenter)' : ' mouseEnter()',
        '[style.background-color]' : 'myColor'
    }
})

mouseEnter(){
    this.myColor = 'blue';
}
```

- Using `@HostBinding` (this case will set the color immediatly)

```js
@HostBinding('style.background-color') get color {
    return this.myColor;
}

mouseEnter(){
    this.myColor = 'blue';
}
```

- Using `Renderer` (use this instead of `nativeElement.style = 'value'`)

```js
constructor(public renderer: Renderer, public element: ElementRef) {}

mouseEnter(){
  this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.myColor);
}
```

Note that `host` and `@HostBinding` are equivalent.

Comment: I have seen using this.element.nativeElement as the target parameter in Observable.fromEvent. Does this answer fits well for this case or do you have some 'legal' alternatives?