# Convert Subject to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I want to run [this example](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-examples/blob/master/rx-draggable/directives/draggable.ts) with `rxjs5`. But it doesn't work. I've stucked on [#41 line](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-examples/blob/master/rx-draggable/directives/draggable.ts#L41). It says that map returns `Subject` and it doesn't have `.takeUntil` method. What is the best way to implement it? Thanks

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @micronyks It's 5.0.0-beta.2

Answer (score 2):

Your example is really old, it's using things like `toRx()` that were deprecated and removed long ago. The example is also using EventEmitters and is subscribing to them and we [should't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076700/what-is-the-proper-use-of-an-eventemitter) and it's also setting values to the DOM using `nativeElement` and we [shouldn't do that either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108995/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-accessing-the-dom-using-nativeelement-in-angu).

So I modified the example a little bit

- I removed EventEmitter and replaced it by Subject
- Removed `toRx()`, no needed anymore
- Used Renderer to set `cursor` and `position` of the element.

This is a little snippet of what the code looks like by now, it's not that different.

```js
  constructor(public element: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(element.nativeElement, 'position', 'relative');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(element.nativeElement, 'cursor', 'pointer');

    this.mousedrag = this.mousedown.map(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        return {
          left: event.clientX - this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left,
          top:  event.clientY - this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
        };
      })
      .flatMap(imageOffset => this.mousemove.map(pos => ({
        top:  pos.clientY - imageOffset.top,
        left: pos.clientX - imageOffset.left
      }))
      .takeUntil(this.mouseup));

  }
```

Here's the [full example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HO1V5occAXcbEK2fyKd?p=preview) working.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I got it :-)

Comment: I like the "shouldn't do that" links :)

Comment: @MarkRajcok hahha :P

Answer (score 0):

From your repo it seems like you are using older version of `Angular2 packages`.
But you may try this, or **Eric Martinez** has given you wonderful working demo.

> **import 'rxjs/Rx';**