# Alternative to ElementRef - Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-hostbinding, elementref

In my ng2 application, I am using an external library which hasn't exposed its HTML elements.

I am using it as:

```
<custom-component>
     <div custom-title> Title </div>
     <div custom-content> Content </div>
</custom-component>
```

Now when it renders in HTML then it is added as:

```
<custom-component>
    <div class='customComponentWrapper'>
         <div class='content'>
               <div custom-title> Title </div>
               <div custom-content> Content </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</custom-component>
```

To change the position dynamically I made a local template reference variable.

```
<custom-component>
     <div #customComponent custom-title> Title </div>
     <div custom-content> Content </div>
</custom-component>
```

And changing its width as:

```
@ViewChild('customComponent') customComponent: ElementRef;

const elem = this.customComponent.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
elem.style.marginRight = width + 'px';
```

> Now A/c to [angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) doc `ElementRef` is going to be deprecated. I am not able to find any other way of doing this. Is there any other way around to achieve the same?

I also some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108995/what-are-some-good-alternatives-to-accessing-the-dom-using-nativeelement-in-angu) on SO. But didn't reach to a solution.

Comment: Nothing in the link you provide says anything about `ElementRef` being deprecated. It says it is a security risk, and to consider using [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer). Am I missing something?

Comment: @R.Richards  Even of go with renderer it is using same native element to change this style.

Comment: better use a directive and inject ElementRef into its constructor